# Ckeditor installation failed

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I'm trying to install Ckeditor on my symfony 4 project (4.1.4);
When I try to :

```
bin/console ckeditor:install
```

I have this error :

```
    Unable to download CKEditor ZIP archive from "https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/archive/full/latest.zip". (file_get_contents(https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/archive/f
  ull/latest.zip): failed to open stream: operation failed)
```

After searching on google, i dont find any solution to solve my problem.

composer -V :1.6.2

I checked my ssl config, `php -r 'print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());'`

```
Array
(
    [default_cert_file] => /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => /usr/local/etc/openssl/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => /usr/local/etc/openssl
    [ini_cafile] => /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
    [ini_capath] =>
)
```

And to finish : `~/Sites/lblblb/feature/translator ●✚  bin/console ckeditor:install -vvv`

```
    Exception trace:
 FOS\CKEditorBundle\Installer\CKEditorInstaller->createException() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/blblb/vendor/friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle/src/Installer/CKEditorInstaller.php:183
 FOS\CKEditorBundle\Installer\CKEditorInstaller->download() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/blblbl/vendor/friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle/src/Installer/CKEditorInstaller.php:113
 FOS\CKEditorBundle\Installer\CKEditorInstaller->install() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/blbll/vendor/friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle/src/Command/CKEditorInstallerCommand.php:112
 FOS\CKEditorBundle\Command\CKEditorInstallerCommand->execute() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/blblbl/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:251
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/blblbl/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:904
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/blbbllb/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:89
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/blblbl/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:262
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/bblbllb/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:75
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/blblbl/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/yahiko/Sites/bblblbl/bin/console:39
```

Thank's :)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Did you try do get https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/archive/full/latest.zip directly?

Comment: No proxy here. 
Where i can put ckeditor folder if i get it directly ?